# Equivalent of CallKit for listening to SMS reception?

Tags: ios, sms, callkit, ancs

It seems quite difficult to get notifications in an app when the phone receives a SMS . I tried to look a solution in ANCS, but it seems that I cannot access to it directly from an application.
There is although CallKit for calls. Is there really no solution for listening to SMS in iOS?

Comment: Just a clarification: CallKit is only usable for VOIP calls and not for normal GSM calls. Have a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit).

Comment: No, for privacy reasons an app cannot access SMS details.

Comment: David Pasztor, it's strange, because when I am calling with another phone an iPhone with an app containing basic CallKit code, the app detects the call ...

Comment: Paulw11, thanks :(

Comment: There's no api or a kit to listen to SMS for iOS.